# Eclipse: checkstyle violations icon decoration

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

Although I find the Checkstyle plugin for Eclipse very useful, I find the way they highlight violation too much. I stripped out the yellow background and the overview ruler, but I haven't figured out the following:

When there are Checkstyle violations, the files containing them appear in the Project Explorer with the same decoration icon as when they have compiler warnings ([image]). All my classes appear infested with warnings, and I can't tell which of them are compiler warnings. The only way I found to keep Checkstyle from changing the file decorations is to turn it off for my projects, but that obviously also hides the violations in the editor.

Is there a way to tell Checkstyle not to change the file icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SourceForge forum ([here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-cs/forums/forum/274377/topic/3592682?message=8146779)) for the project, they say that it is not possible to change the decoration, but what can be done instead is to change the severity of the violations.