# Checkstyle for Eclipse: Error decorator icon in package explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

Currently I'm using Eclipse 4.2 and I wonder if I could change the checkstyle decorator icons in the package explorer, so they won't look like compiler warnings/errors anymore. This is so annoying that some poeple turn off checkstyle completely.

Obviously, other plugins like m2e can put their own decorator icons to the java files, so does anyone know a way  to do this or where to start with (to change the source code of the checkstyle plugin to do this)?

I saw [Eclipse: checkstyle violations icon decoration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039611/eclipse-checkstyle-violations-icon-decoration) but it is about two years old and things might have changed in these two years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change the severity of each issue as shown in the upper left corner of the configuration dialog below.

You should clearly NOT try to modify the overlays. Either an issue has a warning level or not. If it has a warning level, it should show a warning overlay, independent of where the warning originated (compiler or other plugin).

So if you don't like warnings being shown there, either decrease the severity of the issues or remove the check for the issue completely. You don't really gain anything by first checking for style violations and then trying to hide them immediately afterwards.

[image]